# What high level network object passing facilities exist in squeak/pharo?

Tags: networking, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

The squeak webpage says: Squeak provides programatic access to the networking environment of your computer at all levels, from high level object passing

What package should I load to take a look at this high level object passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2288.